# Filter one2many Field In many2one Field

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I have a `one2many` tree field which contains many columns, every column uses a `many2one` field, the picture below shows two columns:

[image]

Is there a way to use a `many2one` field to get the values, let us say for the first column **(prod1, prod2)**.

I am a beginner and do not know where to start from, any suggestions will be much appreciated!

> P.S.: I am working with **odoo v9**

Answer (score 1):

you can use this documentation form odoo:[Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html)

One2many field; the value of such a field is the recordset of all the records in **comodel_name** such that the field **inverse_name** is equal to the current record.
you can use these Parameters:

```
comodel_name -- name of the target model (string)
inverse_name -- name of the inverse Many2one field in comodel_name (string)
domain -- an optional domain to set on candidate values on the client side (domain or string)
context -- an optional context to use on the client side when handling that field (dictionary)
auto_join -- whether JOINs are generated upon search through that field (boolean, by default False)
limit -- optional limit to use upon read (integer)
```

if you need toà use domain like this:

```
field.One2many(comodel_name="model_name", inverse_name="inverse_field_name", string=None, domain=[('filed_name_in_comodel', 'operators', 'Value')])
```